# Configure AWS CloudFront to send custom query params to origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-cloudformation, yaml

Is it possible to configure my AWS CloudFront distribution to append to the request a custom query param (e.g a private key) before sending it to the origin?

For example, the front end is calling ***.cloudfront.net/get**
and CloudFront forwarding the request to **custom-server.com/get?key=MY-PRIVATE-KEY**

I didn't find details regarding it online, but did find that you can add [custom headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-origincustomheader.html) which makes me suspect that it's possible.

If it's indeed possible, a follow-up question would be how can it be done using CloudFormation yaml config code.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve. Sounds like something you might do with Lambda @ Edge or (probably not but worth looking at) the new Cloudfront Functions ( https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-cloudfront-functions-run-your-code-at-the-edge-with-low-latency-at-any-scale/ )

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the suggestion. I'm aiming to forward a call from the front end to an outside api using an API key that I don't want the world to see, and I was hoping it can be done with the Cloudfront configuration by itself (without lambda edge). You suspect it cannot be done?

Comment: Not with CloudFront, that's a CDN. I'd need to see a picture of your architecture to give more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the query string sent to origin with a cloudwatch function that you add to the "Viewer Request" on cloudfront behavior. Here is an example

```
function handler(event) {
  event.request.querystring.key = {value:'MY-PRIVATE-KEY'}; 
  return event.request;
}
```